# How to assign a value to a nullable through reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, system.reflection, propertyinfo

How do I set a `Nullable<T>` value through reflection?
I was able to set values that are not `Nullable<T>` and detect if a type is of type `Nullable<T>` but I don't find a way how to set this value properly.

This is the current snippet:

```
public bool SetProperty(string propertyLambdaString, object value)
{
    try
    {
        ParameterExpression paramParty = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TModel), "model");
        MemberExpression property = BuildPropertyExpression(paramParty, propertyLambdaString);
        ParameterExpression paramValue = Expression.Parameter(value.GetType(), "value");

        if (Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(property.Type) != null)
        {
            // TODO: Question: How to assign a value to a nullable? Assign throws exception.
            //Expression assignmentExp = Expression.Assign(property, paramValue);
            //LambdaExpression lambda = Expression.Lambda(
            //  assignmentExp,
            //  new List<ParameterExpression> { paramParty, paramValue });
            //lambda.Compile().DynamicInvoke(this.model, value);

            return false;
        }

        // TODO: Question: How to set a value to null?
        Expression assignmentExp = Expression.Assign(property, paramValue);
        LambdaExpression lambda = Expression.Lambda(
            assignmentExp,
            new List<ParameterExpression> { paramParty, paramValue });
        lambda.Compile().DynamicInvoke(this.model, value);
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        Logger.Error(exception);
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

// find delimiters and build MemberExpression for nested properties
private static MemberExpression BuildPropertyExpression(Expression param, string propertyLambdaString)
{
    int firstDelim = propertyLambdaString.IndexOf('.');
    if (firstDelim < 0)
    {
        return Expression.Property(param, propertyLambdaString);
    }

    string head = propertyLambdaString.Substring(0, firstDelim);
    string tail = propertyLambdaString.Substring(firstDelim + 1);
    MemberExpression expr = BuildPropertyExpression(param, head);
    return BuildPropertyExpression(expr, tail);
}
```

Comment: A bit short on time here atm, but a quick thought - are you assigning `Nullable<T>.Value` or are you reassigning the entire `Nullable<T>`? It's a struct so I would assume you need to reassign the whole thing.

Comment: Also creating and compiling expressions that you then throw away seems like a waste compared to using plain old reflection.

Comment: @Chris How to do it without compile then?

Comment: Was not able to get it work for nested properties in an other way, suggestions for improval are always welcome ;-)

Comment: ... and to answer your question: I want to assign the Value of a Nullable. And the problem is: if you have a value that is a non nullable this can't be assigned to the nullable<T>. If it is possible to create nullable type (using reflection) from the given value (e.g. double to Nullable<double>) then it is also ok.